# Turn text after slashes into variables with HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirectstandardoutput

I need to pass 3 variables with a URL but using slashes. So for example I would use this URL:

http://www.example.com/variable1/variable2/variable3

I have this in my HTACCESS which allows the text after the first variable to be passed but I can't get the other two to come through, even if I add &$2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ process.php?width=$1&height=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Any links or help would be great

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are only capturing one variable in your rewrite rule.

You need something like:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ process.php?width=$1&height=$2&third=$3 [QSA,L]
```

or, a bit shorter:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ process.php?width=$1&height=$2&third=$3 [QSA,L]
```

(the `\w` word character includes letters, digits and underscores)

I have made only the ending slash optional so this rewrite rule would only do something if there are exactly 3 variables.

Comment: @Fraggy I normally use multiple rewrite rules for that, so first the rule with 3 vars, then the rule with 2 and then the rule with only 1. You could also enclose the optional variables in nested non-capturing parenthesis.

Answer (score 6):

You might find it easier to grab the parameters in the .php file, via:

```
$pathinfo = isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])
    ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
    : $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];

$params = preg_split('|/|', $pathinfo, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($params);
```

So calling the script with this:

http://www.example.com/variable1/variable2/variable3

would return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => variable1
    [1] => variable2
    [2] => variable3
)
```

This will work for both:

http://www.example.com/variable1/variable2/variable3 and
http://www.example.com/process.php/variable1/variable2/variable3