# Nginx server create url for mvc in php

Tags: php, url, nginx, rewriting

I am using NGINX. I am going to develop a MVC framework. 
Now Url is like 
http://localhost/my_mvc/index.php?arg1=1&arg2=2&...

I would like to make url like 
http://localhost/my_mvc/index/1/2..

I am able to do this in Apache using .htaccess but not able to do in nginx. I am having multiple project in local so I would like to create this rules for only current directory name "my_mvc". Anyone can help me to find out solution for this problem?

Comment: This might help http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Nginx to separate variables with slashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255944/how-to-use-nginx-to-separate-variables-with-slashes)