# Is it possible to get URL slash/ parameters with simple php?

Tags: php

is it possible to get parameters like:
`index.php/bar/foo` with php?
I know that I can use s.th. like `index.php?a=bar&b=foo` and the user `$_GET['a']`. But I need to do it with the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: As DanFromGermany pointed out it is actually possible to have urls like index.php/bar/foo without using mod_rewrite or such. I guess the key here is to have a filename (index.php) in the url.

This has to be done in the web server.

In apache there is a module called mod_rewrite which can rewrite urls like index.php/bar/foo to another format such as index.php?a=bar&b=foo.

Examples, and a description of the topic: http://www.seochat.com/c/a/search-engine-optimization-help/creating-search-engine-friendly-urls-with-php/

What web server are you using?

Comment: Ah okay thank you. I'm using a apache webserver. But this ansers my question, because I just wanted to know if its possible with pure php

Comment: check the htaccess for this kind of url rewrite http://stackoverflow.com/a/12229240/2706194

Comment: Apache's default behaviour is to map `index.php/xx/xx` to `index.php?xx/xx`.

Answer (score 5):

The answers here just look like guesses. mod_rewrite presumes apache webserver (we don't know which one you use) and is way too much for this simple task.

Apache's default behaviour is to map `index.php/xx/xx` to `index.php?xx/xx`.

Look how easy this is:

```
$args = explode('/', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

print_r($args);
```

Comment: Very good information, thank you! I just tried it on my local installation and it worked.

Comment: DanFromGermany: This is just out of curiosity: what happens if you have an url like http://mysite/index/bar/foo? Then you would have to use mod_rewrite or something similar, right?

Comment: @DavidAbrahamsson Yes, when you want to hide the `.php` and other things you need to use `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 1):

I used following code to access slash parameters:

```
$args = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$arg_arr = explode("/",$args);
print_r($arg_arr);
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same either you work on httpd.conf for rewriting the URL or use PHP framework like codeigniter etc. which provide inbuilt functionality.

Comment: Also, you can do it via `.htaccess`