# How to resize images from URL directly

Tags: image

http://example.com/unsafe/184x147/top/http://www.example.com/abc.jpg

In the link above the image is resized from url by passing the image dimensions , position , and source image .

Can someone please explain what is the process that is actually happening here ?

Comment: more explain about your question

Comment: all I see here is a link to a .jpg.  There isn't any code here to analyze.  However, even if there were, this isn't the right site to ask people to decode other people's work.

Comment: No iam not asking to decode . I want to know if we can get url parameters directly from URL . If url is like this abc.com/ ...jpg?a=100 we can get the variable 'a' . But in the above example there is no such thing . How can we get the variables from such URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example :
http://www.example.com/variable1/variable2/variable3

You might find it easier to grab the parameters in the .php file, via:

```
$pathinfo = isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])
    ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
    : $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];

$params = preg_split('|/|', $pathinfo, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($params);
```

would return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => variable1
    [1] => variable2
    [2] => variable3
)
```

[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229222/turn-text-after-slashes-into-variables-with-htaccess)